# ffmpeg RTP audio multicast stream choppy

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream .wav audio files via RTP multicast. I'm using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i Melody_file.wav -f rtp rtp://224.0.1.211:5001
```

It successfully initiates the stream. However, the audio comes out very choppy. Any ideas how I can make the audio stream clean? I do not need any video at all. Below is a screenshot of my output:

[image]

Comment: What software are you using to play back the stream? You could try to increase a) UDP socket receiver buffers in the case where packets are being dropped by the OS b) RTP jitter buffer or application play out buffer to smooth out your playback.

Comment: I have a yealink VoIP phone listening on the multicast address. From phone to phone when i multicast the same audio file there is no issues. But when i'm multicasting with ffmpeg it's constantly chopping. I tried pkt_size and one thing i noticed is that numbers 300 or lower creates a lot of choppyness but i've tried a really high number it doesnt become perfect.

Comment: I guess I would try to capture the traffic with tcpdump or wireshark to see what the differences are between phone to phone and ffmpeg to phone. Are you sure that the phone is sending pcm mulaw when it transmits the file? What happens when you send compressed audio (I'm sure the VOIP phone has several built in codecs) or do you need to send pcm?

Comment: I think it could be the codec issue. The VoIP phone is set to a multicast codec of G722 but the wav file is PCM MULAW. So maybe I need to change the codec setting on the voip phone, i see a codec option of PCMU maybe i need to select that? I will try that on Monday

Comment: @Ralf I tried changing the Multicast Codec to PCMU on the voip phone but still have the exact same issue. I have the jitter settings on the phone and I tried playing around with that and it makes no difference whatsoever. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this will help at all, but what if you compress the audio on the sender side with ffmpeg and stream that instead?

Comment: @Ralf i just tried that still no difference. One thing I noticed makes a difference is if after the port number in the URL like this rtp://224.0.1.211:5001 if i put ?pkt_size= and if i put anything under 300 it sounds even worse and when I increase it, it improves but ive tried the max number and it still doesnt become clear it's still choppy

Comment: @Ralf i've just noticed that setting a filter in ffmpeg like this -filter_complex "aresample=8000,asetnsamples=n=160" the saples of 160 value seems to reduce the choppyness quite a lot but it's still chopping. If i increase it or decrease it then it goes worse again. So it must have something to do with the way ffmpeg isn't sending it correctly?

Comment: are you able/have you tried to sniff the traffic between phones? Perhaps that could give you some clues. I would also just stream ffmpeg to ffmpeg for comparison sake. I doubt the problem lies in ffmpeg itself, it's just streaming the data, but perhaps there's some mismatch in configuration that's causing the choppy audio. Also I would try figure out the cause of the choppy audio i.e. is it packet loss or really high jitter? That could give you some clues in which direction to go. Unfortunately I don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: @Ralf I've made quite a bit of breakthrough. FIrstly my WAV files are phone system compatible with 8000Hz 16Bit PCM. But for some reason for ffmpeg to be able to multicast to the phone nicely I have to save the WAV file as 8000Hz 32Bit PCM. anything above 8000Hz doesnt work. So what I did is saved the file as 32Bit PCM 8K Hz but then I still need to put this filter in ffmpeg "asetnsamples=n=160" Any idea what this 160 setting is?

Comment: Cool, See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetnsamples. Also interesting is http://wiki.snom.com/Category:HowTo:Multicast_Audio "the switch -filter_complex 'aresample=8000,asetnsamples=n=160' is needed in order to fix the RTP palyload size. "

Comment: Thank you. That Snom wiki basically says exactly what issue I had, I have to use that and make sure my WAV file is 32bit and it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some examples expanding upon the useful comments between @Ralf and @Ahmed about setting [`asetnsamples`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#asetnsamples) and [`aresample`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aresample), and also those mentioned in the [Snom wiki](https://service.snom.com/display/wiki/Multicast+Audio). Basically one can get smoother multicast transmission/playback using these approaches for G711/mulaw audio:

```
ffmpeg -re -i Melody_file.wav -filter_complex 'aresample=8000,asetnsamples=n=160' -acodec pcm_mulaw -ac 1 -f rtp rtp://224.0.1.211:5001
```

Or using higher quality G722 audio codec:

```
ffmpeg -re -i Melody_file.wav -filter_complex 'aresample=16000,asetnsamples=n=160' -acodec g722 -ac 1 -f rtp rtp://224.0.1.211:5001
```